# Access Mac's live sound output data

Tags: java, macos, api, audio, visualizer

I'm trying to create a program that accesses my Mac's live sound output data which is used to display a live graphic waveform of the current sound/song (AKA I play a song through youtube/itunes/etc and this program shows the waveform of the song while it is playing). I understand I will most likely be using Java Sound API and will need to use a FFT algorithm to get the data into the frequency domain, but I can't find any way to access the live sound output data? Any suggestions?